# Locking for each property

Tags: c#, locking

I'm looking at some code that I don't understand the point of.

```
private object myProperty_lock = new Object();
private SomeType myProperty_backing;

public SomeType MyProperty
{
    get { lock(myProperty_lock) { return myProperty_backing; } }
    set { lock(myProperty_lock) { myProperty_backing = value; } }
}
```

- This pattern is used many times within the same class.
- Each time this pattern is used, there's a new lock object. (It's not a shared lock object for all properties.)
- The types used are reference types and primitives. (No non-primitive structs.)

Does this code do *anything*? References & primitives are assigned atomically, so we don't need to protect against a thread switch in the middle of the assignment. The lock object isn't used anywhere else, so there's no protection there.

Is there something with memory barriers, perhaps? I had assumed that a lock inside a method didn't affect things outside of that method.

Comment: This indicates that the author of the code doesn't understand thread safety.

Comment: Almost certainly SLaks is right here. Since assignment is already guaranteed atomic, and the lock is over when the get returns, it's difficult to see what this does for thread safety. (It is, however, entirely possible that correct thread safety would not use a class-wide lock.)

Comment: Agreed, a single lock for all these properties would not be correct. (But it would not be nothing, which the individual locks might be.)

Answer (score 0):

The fact that code is inside a method does not imply a memory barrier. So you may be on the right track for suspecting that the locks are for that fresh read memory guarantees.

Of course it also could have been added due to the person adding it was a [cargo cult programmer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) and did not understand why to do it and only did it because he saw a code example that does it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see here is that by using `lock` the developer indicates a concern regarding thread safety. They thought that concurrent threads might be accessing this property.

My first question would be whether that's actually the case - is there concurrent access to this property?

There might be a valid scenario, but is there a reason why any number of threads might be able to set that reference? What sort of logic is happening if one thread sets the property, presumably for some valid reason, only to have it immediately overwritten by another thread? How is the application doing something predictable? Did the reference set by the previous caller just not matter? Then why did it set the property?

And what about the object - `SomeType` - returned from the property? Now any number of threads can have a reference to the same instance. Can `SomeType` can be altered, and if so, is it thread safe?

I normally wouldn't wonder, but when I see something that looks odd with multithreading I like to dig a little deeper. Maybe they have it all patched together and it works, but sometimes they don't.